# Blazor WebAPI call returns partial model

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

I'm assuming this is something to do with Newtonsoft.Json...
We are making an ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor Webassembly app (starting with the Visual Studio template).
When I call the WebAPI for a custom view model, it only returns some of the properties in the model.

Model:

```
    public class FormViewModel
    {
        public Models.Form Form { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Models.Role> Roles { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Models.Role>();
        public ObservableCollection<Models.IdentifiedViewModelObject> Answers = new ObservableCollection<IdentifiedViewModelObject>();
        public ObservableCollection<string> Cells = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ObservableCollection<string> Lines = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ObservableCollection<string> Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
```

I verify that all of the class properties do get values.

But the WebAPI, looking at browser dev tools in chromium edge, returns this model:

```
{
   lpaForm : {...},
   roles: [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally realized I was missing getters/setters on the missing properties.